# Passing array to callback function in void parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, void-pointers

A have callback function with this prototype:

```
void serverAnswer(void *pUserData, int flag);
```

I need to pass a buffer `const uint8_t *buf` to this function using the void parameter.
How do i pass the buffer, and how can i access the elements of the buffer in the function?

Example (not working):

Call:

```
const uint8_t *buf;
int buf_len = 3;
serverAnswer(&buf, buf_len);
```

Access to buffer:

```
void serverAnswer(void *pUserData, int flag) {

uint8_t* p = (uint8_t *)pUserData;
uint8_t data = p[0];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&buf` is a `const uint8_t **`. What you actually want to do is pass `buf` to `serverAnswer`, you'll need a `const_cast` to allow conversion from a `const` pointer to `void*`:

```
const uint8_t* buf;
serverAnswer(const_cast<uint8_t*>(buf), buf_len);
```

To avoid undefined behaviour you should put the `const` back in `serverAnswer`:

```
void serverAnswer(void *pUserData, int flag) {

const uint8_t* p = (const uint8_t *)pUserData;
uint8_t data = p[0];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I realized that my question was erraneous, i modified it. The task is not to pass the buffer, but the pointer to the buffer. See above.

Comment: same applies, you are still passing in a pointer to a pointer but casting it back to just a pointer

Comment: I if call serverAnswer(buf, buf_len) (without &) the compiler complains the call.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually passing a pointer to the array during your call. In your code, what  you're casting back to an `uint8_t*`, is an `uint8_t**`.

What you need to do, is either passing the array directly, or casting it to `uint8_t**` instead of `uint8_t*` and dereferencing it.

IMHO, passing the array directly is the best way to go, because passing a pointer to a pointer is not needed when you don't want to modify the pointed pointer, which seems to be your case

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think this is a great answer, but maybe you could include an example of _how_ to do what you're prescribing.